# how to make a description box on click on ay word ( pop up window or box ) and that should disappear on click it again in latex not in beamer class?

Tags: href

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article} % Note: uses twoside option
\usepackage[a4paper, marginparwidth=75pt, total={10cm, 10cm}]{geometry} % To create a small page
\usepackage{hyperref} % To use the \url command (in the footnote)
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}   

\begin{document}
\section{Lorem Ipsum}
But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of reprobating pleasure and extolling pain arose. To do so,    

\tikzstyle{buttonstyle} = [rectangle, draw = black!80,  font={\sffamily\bfseries}, text=black]

\newcommand*{\button}[1]{\tikz{\node[buttonstyle] {#1};}}
   
Press \button{F5} for help !

\fcolorbox{black}{white}{\begin{minipage}{15em}
  The quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox 
  jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy 
  dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox 
  jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy 
  dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox 
  jumps right over the lazy dog.
\end{minipage}}
       
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Thanks for the code. // Please Edit your question and explain a little bit more what you want, what doesn't happen etc. Because the way it is, it will probably be flagged as a low-quality post, soon.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i need something like cooltooltips